# Solving a system of equations takes too long

Tags: equation-solving, date-and-time

I was trying to solve a system of 4 equations with Mathematica but it took too long (running for hours) without any output. I have tried many ways without any success. I need your help. Thank you in advance
Here's the code to my problem:

```
ClearAll[α, s, m, μ, σ, δ, b, n, l, j, l]
m = 1.5; 
s = 1; 
ℏ = 1; 
μ = 1.5/2; 
j = 1; 
n = 2; 
l = 1; 

NSolve[{(3*
   b)/δ + ((16*α*
     Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
     m^2))*(1 - (6*σ^2)/δ^2) - 
      (μ/(2*ℏ^2))*(((4*α)/
       3 + (3*b)/δ^2 - (128*α*σ^2*
         Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/
                  (9*m^2*δ^3))/(3/2 + 
      Sqrt[(2*μ*
           b)/(ℏ^2*δ^3) - (96*α*σ^2*
           Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*
                         (s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
           m^2*δ^4) + (l + 1/2)^2]))^2 == 3.097, 
  (3*b)/δ + ((16*α*
     Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
     m^2))*(1 - (6*σ^2)/δ^2) - 
      (μ/(2*ℏ^2))*(((4*α)/
       3 + (3*b)/δ^2 - (128*α*σ^2*
         Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/
                  (9*m^2*δ^3))/(5/2 + 
      Sqrt[(2*μ*
           b)/(ℏ^2*δ^3) - (96*α*σ^2*
           Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*
                         (s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
           m^2*δ^4) + (l + 1/2)^2]))^2 == 3.686, 
  (3*b)/δ + ((16*α*
     Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
     m^2))*(1 - (6*σ^2)/δ^2) - 
      (μ/(2*ℏ^2))*(((4*α)/
       3 + (3*b)/δ^2 - (128*α*σ^2*
         Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/
                  (9*m^2*δ^3))/(7/2 + 
      Sqrt[(2*μ*
           b)/(ℏ^2*δ^3) - (96*α*σ^2*
           Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*
                         (s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
           m^2*δ^4) + (l + 1/2)^2]))^2 == 4.039, 
  (3*b)/δ + ((16*α*
     Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
     m^2))*(1 - (6*σ^2)/δ^2) - 
      (μ/(2*ℏ^2))*(((4*α)/
       
       3 + (3*b)/δ^2 - (128*α*σ^2*
         Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/
                  (9*m^2*δ^3))/(9/2 + 
      Sqrt[(2*μ*
           b)/(ℏ^2*δ^3) - (96*α*σ^2*
           Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*
                         (s*(s + 1) - 3/2))/(9*
           m^2*δ^4) + (l + 1/2)^2]))^2 == 3.927}, {b, σ, δ, α}]
```

Comment: Well, in V 13.1 it finished in 3 seconds for me.  Screen shot. It says no solution exist ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3pXb.png)

Comment: On v12.2.0-Win7-z64 and with the code as provided, I get the output `{ }` as well. It is up to the OP to communicate further with respondents. Perhaps it is a version issue in which case the OP can include the output of `$Version` to the post, if the situation has not improved. I am casting the first vote to close it.

Answer (score 4):

**There are no solutions.** OPs system has the form

```
eqs=Table[a[1]-a[2]/((2*i+1)/2+a[3])^2==r[i],{i,1,4}]
(* {a[1]-a[2]/(3/2+a[3])^2==r[1],
    a[1]-a[2]/(5/2+a[3])^2==r[2],
    a[1]-a[2]/(7/2+a[3])^2==r[3],
    a[1]-a[2]/(9/2+a[3])^2==r[4]} *)
```

The right hand sides `r[_]` are given numbers. The 4 unknown only appear inside the 3 expressions `a[_]` (see `as` further below). This means that the system will only be solvable if the `r[_]` satisfy some constraint:

```
constraint=Eliminate[eqs,Array[a,3]]
(* r[1]^3 (25 r[2]^2-320 r[2] r[3]+1024 r[3]^2+270 r[2] r[4]-1728 r[3] r[4]+729 r[4]^2)+r[1]^2 (-27 r[2]^3+297 r[2]^2 r[3]-1728 r[2] r[3]^2-291 r[2]^2 r[4]+3822 r[2] r[3] r[4]-1344 r[3]^2 r[4]-2025 r[2] r[4]^2+2025 r[3] r[4]^2-729 r[4]^3)+r[1] (54 r[2]^3 r[3]+675 r[2]^2 r[3]^2-2106 r[2]^2 r[3] r[4]+2106 r[2] r[3]^2 r[4]+1344 r[2]^2 r[4]^2-3822 r[2] r[3] r[4]^2+291 r[3]^2 r[4]^2+1728 r[2] r[4]^3-270 r[3] r[4]^3)
   ==27 r[2]^3 r[3]^2-27 r[2]^2 r[3]^3+675 r[2]^2 r[3]^2 r[4]+54 r[2] r[3]^3 r[4]-1728 r[2]^2 r[3] r[4]^2+297 r[2] r[3]^2 r[4]^2-27 r[3]^3 r[4]^2+1024 r[2]^2 r[4]^3-320 r[2] r[3] r[4]^3+25 r[3]^2 r[4]^3 *)
```

The right hand side provided by OP is

```
rs={r[1]->3.097,r[2]->3.686,r[3]->4.039,r[4]->3.927}
```

and does not satisfy the constraint

```
constraint /. rs
(* False *)
```

Therefore there is no simultaneous solution of all equations.

**Least squares solution.** We can try to solve in the sense of least squares. Whether this is useful depends on the application. Let me first solve for the `a[_]` using least squares:

```
asol=Last[NMinimize[eqs[[;;,1]]-eqs[[;;,2]]/.rs//#.#&,Array[a,3]]]
(* {a[1]->4.12309,a[2]->2.59766,a[3]->0.0878762} *)
```

To compute the unknown, note that

```
as=With[{m=1.5,s=1,ℏ=1,μ=1.5/2,j=1,n=2,l=1},
{
  a[1]->(3*b)/δ+((16*α*Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s+1)-3/2))/(9*m^2))*(1-(6*σ^2)/δ^2),
  a[2]->(μ/(2*ℏ^2))*(((4*α)/3+(3*b)/δ^2-(128*α*σ^2*Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s+1)-3/2))/(9*m^2*δ^3)))^2,
  a[3]->Sqrt[(2*μ*b)/(ℏ^2*δ^3)-(96*α*σ^2*Pi*(σ/Sqrt[Pi])^3*(s*(s+1)-3/2))/(9*m^2*δ^4)+(l+1/2)^2]}];
```

The given values for the `a[_]` yield 3 equations for the 4 unkown `{σ,δ,b,α}`, meaning there will be a 1-dimensional solution set. We can find solution instances by fixing one arbitrarily, for example

```
sols=NSolve[Join[{σ==1},Equal@@@as/.asol],Reals]
{{σ->1.,δ->-0.81368,b->-2.65955,α->3.1622},
 {σ->1.,δ->-0.531035,b->-1.5979,α->1.08509}}
```

These are approximate solutions:

```
eqs[[;;,1]]/.as/.sols
(* {{3.09282,3.73521,3.92129,3.99967},
    {3.09282,3.73521,3.92129,3.99967}} *)
```

These numbers are close to `rs` above but not equal, since we used least squares.

Answer (score 1):

- `Rationalize` the equations.

```
equations//Rationalize[#, 0] &
```

[image]

And

```
Reduce[equations//Rationalize[#, 0] &,{b, σ, δ, α}]
```

> `False`.

It means that there no solutions.

- Maybe use `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` to find such `{b, σ, δ, α}`.